# Why I am getting this "This function must return a value of type View" error despite the interface function is returning void?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have the following function without issue.

```
calendarSection.onMonthChangeListener = CalendarView.OnMonthChangeListener { year, month ->
    val string = getHumanReadableMonthYearString(year, month)

    (activity as? MainActivity)?.setToolbarTextView(string)
}
```

If I refactor the code to the following with early return

```
calendarSection.onMonthChangeListener = CalendarView.OnMonthChangeListener { year, month ->
    val mainActivity = activity as? MainActivity ?: return

    val string = getHumanReadableMonthYearString(year, month)

    mainActivity.setToolbarTextView(string)
}
```

I am getting the following error at the early return statement.

> "This function must return a value of type View"

After several trial-n-error, I figure out I need to write the code in the following way

```
calendarSection.onMonthChangeListener = CalendarView.OnMonthChangeListener { year, month ->
    val mainActivity = activity as? MainActivity ?: return@OnMonthChangeListener

    val string = getHumanReadableMonthYearString(year, month)

    mainActivity.setToolbarTextView(string)
}
```

May I know why is it so?

The interface is a legacy Java interface. It is returning void. Hence, when compiler mentions I should return `View`, I am getting confused.

```
public class CalendarView
    public interface OnMonthChangeListener {
        void onMonthChange(int year, int month);
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this is the relevant docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/returns.html#return-to-labels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin has to know what block `return` refers to. It's more strict than in Java. Example:

```kotlin
fun test1() {
    run {
        //This return returns only from this run block
        return@run
    }
    
    run name@{
        //We can also add a custom name to this block
        return@name
    }
    
    run {
        //This return returns from the whole function test1!
        return
    }
    
    run {
        //This never runs, because we returned in the previous run block
    }
}
```

Read more about it [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/returns.html)

Answer (score 3):

Returns from inside lambda functions must be labeled to distinguish them from returns from the outer function that the lambda is declared within. Java doesn't need this restriction because it doesn't have inline lambdas, so you can't return from the outer function from within a lambda--nothing to distinguish.

Even though a listener isn't an inline lambda, the restriction is still there for consistent syntax throughout the language.